# Using categories to style each blog post excerpt in a grid?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add the category names as class name to each post on a blog grid using a function.

Thank you for your inputs I would like to add a function in functions.php file without having to edit any other file.

Structure of the post grid

```html
<ul class="blog-grid">

<li class="post-id-1"> blog post </li>
<li class="post-id-2"> blog post </li>
<li class="post-id-3"> blog post </li>

</ul>
```

After searching a lot it appears WordPress only support function to add categories to body class?

Is it possible to use a function in functions.php and extract category name using post-id for each post in the grid and apply it as a class name so the posts can be styled differently for each category?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  post_class() function into class attribute.

Modify your html like this

```
<div class=" <?php post_class( 'common-class-for-post ' ); ?>" itemprop="blogPost"> blog post here </div>
```

You can check this link- [post_class()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_class/)
Try that then let me know the result.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use get_the_category() to get the post category name https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/

```
$categories = get_the_category();
<div class="common-class-for-post post-id-1 <?php if (!empty( $categories)) {echo esc_html( $categories[0]->name );   } ?>"> blog post here </div>
```